# Open Multiple XTerm Windows Simultaniously

Tags: shell, raspberry-pi, xterm, magic-mirror

I am working on a Raspberry Pi powered Magic Mirror project and to start the program I execute a shell script that runs in the background continuously. To make the AI part of my project work I need to open a *second* shell script in the background that also runs continuously. My problem occurs when I try to execute my Xterm commands it waits for the first script to complete before it starts the *second* script. Since both scripts have no designated end point I am stuck. Is there a way to make both Xterm commands execute at the same time?

Here is my current code to start the Xterm sessions:

```
cd ~/MMStartAll

xterm -e "cd ~/MMStartAll; ./AssistantStart.sh"
xterm -e "cd ~/MMStartAll; ./MMStart.sh"

$SHELL
```

Comment: Run the first `xterm` cmd in the background by appending a `&` at the end of the line. You may need/want to add a `sleep 5` before the 2nd `xterm` starts. But StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. RPi Qs are generally more forgiving at https:/raspberrypi.stackexchange.com ;-) .  Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you and my apologies for posting this in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script should end with a `&`. This means that both the xterms will run in a sepperate process id (pid).

```
cd ~/MMStartAll

xterm -e "cd ~/MMStartAll; ./AssistantStart.sh" &
xterm -e "cd ~/MMStartAll; ./MMStart.sh" &

$SHELL
```